# Getting reputation points for community wiki posts, is this a bug?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, community-wiki

[This is the post that got upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242293/242321#242321), you'll see that it links to an answer marked "community wiki". I don't think this is the first time I've noticed it, but I haven't done research to show other examples. Is this a bug? I think it is. The StackOverflow FAQ says:

> (Note that votes for any posts marked "community wiki" do not generate reputation.)

Edit: to be clear, I did see my reputation go up (and no other upvotes to connect with it), so it's not just an error in reporting on the "mail icon" page.

Edit again: I don't think the 16 hours thing is accurate. My answer has no revision history. The parent question was made community wiki on Dec 26.

Comment: I think this is the answer the question is about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242293/242321#242321

Comment: Yes, and that one---according to the tooltip---has only been CW for 16 hours.

Comment: Didn't realize the recent page is private, edited with new link.

Comment: Jeff, you marked it as by design, but I still don't understand. Is it by design that I got rep for a wiki post? Or is the 16 hours accurate? What's up?

Answer (score 3):

The post was made a community wiki after you received your reputation. Your answer was on 28-Oct and the community wiki conversion was done on 8-Dec.

When using the moderator tools or when the Community user converts a question to a wiki question, the answers are also converted without any revision history.

However it would require an SO moderator to confirm whether it was this that made the reputation go up.

Comment: I didn't change it to community wiki. If I remember correctly, one cannot switch another's posts to community wiki.

Comment: Er rather, I didn't change it to community wiki 16 hours ago. I thought that I did well before that, but I can't demonstrate that of course.

Comment: Moderator's (including the community user) can.

Comment: The complete question was changed according to the edit history available here: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/242293/list