# Bug: my reputation history shows points for community wiki answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, community-wiki

My reputation history shows 140 points for my answers to the question [Are there famous developers using Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16137/are-there-famous-developers-using-stackoverflow) which is a community wiki. The question was migrated from stackoverflow.com on Aug 21 2009. I got 14 upvotes before migration and 24 upvotes after migration. Upvotes I got after migration are not shown. The question was made community wiki on Dec 11 2008.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Bug in reputation history]

Comment: This is indeed a bug with *historical* data that isn't apparent at all until digging into it.  To be clear these **are not affecting your rep**, the reputation calc correctly ignores these, but the denormalized data the reputation view in the profile uses needs a bit of love...we'll give it some.

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16670/getting-reputation-points-for-community-wiki-posts-is-this-a-bug ?

Comment: @Nick, I missed this report when posting mine 2 days ago: [Reputation shown in graph, and mortarboard awarded, for CW posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87190/reputation-shown-in-graph-and-mortarboard-awarded-for-cw-posts) Hence, are you sure it's about *historical* data? (True, in my report it's about data for April 11th, which I noticed on April 13th. Anyway, kudos for Community for poking this question!)

Comment: (No, not a dupe, @Daniel. See the comments at Jeff's answer below: this is about posts that were CW before the reputation was earned. Not the other way around.)

Comment: Bumped by Community twice!  Maybe it's a sign...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Votes like these are now fixed in the [new recalcs and rep syncs happening behind the scenes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes), you'll no longer see invalid vote values in the reputation screen.

Actually, you're not seeing the same source of data *at all*, but the vote values are being fixed under the covers, I promise!

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything wrong with this?

Maybe I am misunderstanding you, but **rep gained before the date a question becomes community wiki** is still valid rep.

It's the votes *after* the cwiki date that have a value of 0.

Comment: The question was made community wiki on dec 11 '08, that is, when it was asked! I started to get upvotes in the next year!